# Accessing global attribute of a NetCDF-based coverage in GeoServer as a service

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

Is there a way to access a global attribute of a NetCDF-based coverage through GeoServer?

Running GeoServer 2.12.0 with netcdf and netcdf-out plugin.

Have tried to look for the option to access it via the wcs:CoverageDescription document.

Comment: Are you looking to do this as part of a WCS operation, or any operation provided by GeoServer?

Comment: I've considered the possibility of doing it using the WMS operation "GetCapabilities" (http://docs.geoserver.org/2.12.0/user/services/wms/reference.html) in combination with OpenLayer's  ol.format.WMSCapabilities (http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.format.WMSCapabilities.html), in which case I need to map the global attribute to an attribute or child of the XML-document returned by the operation. Alternatively I have considered the "DescribeCoverage" operation of WCS in which case I will get a XML-document specific to the layer, instead of to the namespace, and look for a way to format.

Comment: GetCapabilities gives information about the service, names/descriptions of the layers/features,coverages, coordinate references systems offered, names of styles, links to additional metadata, operations available etc. it never gives attribute values for the data itself

Comment: @nmtoken OK - thank you for clarifying. I think it would make sense to publish the global attributes via WCS, e.g. as the element "<element ref="gmlcov:metadata" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>" (http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/2.0/wcsDescribeCoverage.xsd)

Comment: One way could be to add a metadata entry to the coverage (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/coverages.yaml) and then use GeoServer's REST API to retrieve the entry. A workaround could be to store the metadata as a keyword in the coverage, and then retrieve it via WMS